# Can't login through login screen after renaming the username

Tags: command-line, 18.04, login, .desktop, username

I have renamed my username using the steps [explained here](https://linuxtechlab.com/rename-user-in-linux-rename-home-directory/). In terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F1) I can login with my newly created username but when I tried to login using login screen it got stuck in a loop. I then again went back to the terminal (Ctrl+Alt+F1) and login with the new username. When I tried `whoami` there, instead of the new username I got `/home/oldusername`. I tried to repeat this step again `sudo usermod -d /home/new_username -m new_username` but I got `no change` message. How do I solve this problem?

EDIT:

I don't know if this is useful but from the  article I have followed all these steps

1. Rename user in Linux
2. Renaming Home directory
3. Changing UID for the user
4. Renaming the group

I tried to access my old home by `sudo cd /home/olduser` but its showing permission denied.

Comment: Counterquestion: what does the logging show? Especially /var/log/syslog and /var/log/auth.log might contain helpful information.

Comment: If you `ls /home/` do you see `newusername` or `oldusername`?

Comment: Telling us which remote procedure (RP) you "followed" doesn't help us help you for N reasons: 1) It's remote. Will the link exist tomorrow? 2) Reading the RP doesn't tell us how accurately you "followed" it. Did you suffer typos or missed lines? We have. 3) Reading the RP omits the error messages you got on your system. These error messages (and the commands that caused them) are key elements in any diagnosis.

Comment: Edit your Question and show `getent passwd oldname;getent passwd newname`

Comment: @waltinator `getent passwd oldname` returns nothing but `getent passwd newname` returns  `newuser:x:2000:1000:newuser:/home/newuser:/bin/bash`

Comment: @earthmeLon `ls /home/` gives my oldusername

Comment: @earthmeLon waltinator , Can any of you please let me know if their is any possibility of a solution for this problem?